# Getting error `No implicits found for parameter fieldMapper: FieldMapper` while using Squeryl version 0.9.14 with Scala version 2.13.1

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I followed the following steps:

- Ran `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` to create new service of Play framework
- Added the line `libraryDependencies += "org.squeryl" %% "squeryl" % "0.9.14"` to my build.xml file (0.9.14 because that version is compatible with my scala version 2.13.1 as per https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.squeryl/squeryl)
- ran `sbt run` which installed all dependencies. `localhost:9000` opens fine without any errors.
- Added a file `MyEntity.scala` with the following content:

  ```
  import org.squeryl.{KeyedEntity, Schema, Table}
  import org.squeryl.annotations.Column

  case class MyEntity(
                   @Column("id") id: Int = 0,
                   @Column("name") name: String,
                 ) extends KeyedEntity[Int] {
    def this() = this(0, "")
  }

  object MyEntitySchema extends Schema {
    val myEntities: Table[MyEntity] = table[MyEntity]("myEntities")
  }
  ```
- Added another file `MyEntityRetrieval.scala`  with the following content:

  ```
  import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
  import scala.util.Try

  class MyEntityRetrieval {
    def get(key: Int) : Option[MyEntity] = inTransaction { Try(Some(myEntities.get(key))).getOrElse(None) }
  }
  ```
- `sbt run`. No errors. Opened localhost. Showing error: `could not find implicit value for parameter fieldMapper: org.squeryl.internals.FieldMapper`.
- Searched in Google. Didn't find anything useful.

How do I fix this? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following import to the top of `MyEntity.scala`:

```scala
import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
```